# kendo upload allowmultiple autoupload calls the API multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-upload

i am using Kendo upload feature. While have set uploadmultiple option to true and autoupload to false.

If i select 2 files and click on Upload Button, the Save API function is called 2 times, once for each file.

Is it possible to call this function only once with both attachments passed in the parameter ?

```
<input name="attachments" type="file" id="attachments" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#attachments").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "AppConfig")',
                autoUpload: false,
            allowmultiple: true
            }
        });
});
</script>



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{

    if (SaveFiles(attachments)
    {
        return Content("");
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("error");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can try to set `batch: true` in the `async` option of the kendoUpload.

Comment: This might be  a stupid question, but with autoUpload set to false, how do you then get the file to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default selected files will be uploaded in separate requests.

If you want to download them once you need to set the [`async.batch` option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#configuration-async.batch) to `true`:

```
$("#attachments").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "AppConfig")',
        autoUpload: false,
        allowmultiple: true,
        batch: true
    }
});
```

Comment: @nemsev - starting which version of kendo UI is this option available ?

Comment: I don't know, which version are you using where is it missing?